# Recurrence Relation $k_{n+2}=\frac{1-n}{n+2}k_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

*There was an interesting question posted on here earlier today but it seems to have disappeared. With due to respect to the OP, I'll post the same question here from memory. If anyone finds the original please mark this as a duplicate and I'll remove it accordingly.*

Given the recurrence relation 
$$k_{n+2}=\frac{1-n}{n+2}k_n$$
express $k_n$ in terms of $k_0$ and $k_1$.

Comment: You can express kn in termns of k(n-2) and so on, until you reach first or second term. Now you can do some simplification and obtain your formula.

Comment: It is good idea you posted again this problem. It does not look simple (at least to me).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - Thank you! Glad you agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{k_{n + 2} = {1 - n \over n + 2}\,k_{n}.\ \mbox{Express}\ k_{n}\
     \mbox{in terms of}\ k_{0}\ \mbox{and}\ k_{1}:\ {\large ?}}$.
Lets introduce the *generating function*

> $$
> {\cal K}\pars{z} \equiv \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}k_{n}z^{n}\,,\qquad
> \verts{z} < 1
> $$

such that
\begin{align}
0&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{n + 2}k_{n + 2}\,z^{n}
+\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{n - 1}k_{n}\,z^{n}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 2}^{\infty}n\,k_{n}\,z^{n - 2}
+\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}n\,k_{n}\,z^{n} - \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}k_{n}\,z^{n}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{k_{1} \over z}
+\pars{{1 \over z^{2}} + 1}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}n\,k_{n}\,z^{n}
- \sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}k_{n}\,z^{n}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{k_{1} \over z}
+\pars{{1 \over z^{2}} + 1}\,z\,\partiald{}{z}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}k_{n}\,z^{n}
-\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}k_{n}\,z^{n}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{k_{1} \over z}
+\pars{{1 \over z^{2}} + 1}\,z\,\partiald{{\cal K}\pars{z}}{z}
-{\cal K}\pars{z}
\end{align}

> $$
> \partiald{{\cal K}\pars{z}}{z}
> -{z \over 1 + z^{2}}\,\,{\cal K}\pars{z}={k_{1} \over 1 + z^{2}}
> \ \imp\
> \partiald{}{z}\bracks{{\cal K}\pars{z} \over \root{1 + z^{2}}}
> ={k_{1} \over \pars{1 + z^{2}}^{3/2}}
> $$

$$
{{\cal K}\pars{z} \over \root{1 + z^{2}}} - k_{0}
=k_{1}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{z}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + t^{2}}^{3/2}}}
^{\dsc{z \over \root{1 + z^{2}}}}\ =\
{k_{1}\,z \over \root{1 + z^{2}}}
$$

> \begin{align}
> {\cal K}\pars{z}&=k_{1}\,z + k_{0}\root{1 + z^{2}}
> =k_{1}\,z + k_{0}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n}z^{2n}
> =k_{1}\,z + k_{0}
> \sum_{\atop{n\ =\ 0 \atop n\ \mbox{even}}}^{\infty}{1/2 \choose n/2}z^{n}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large k_{n}}
=\color{#66f}{\large\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
0 & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is odd}\  \wedge\ n \not= 1
\\[2mm]
k_{1} & \mbox{if} & n = 1
\\[2mm]
k_{0}{1/2 \choose n/2} & \mbox{if} & n\ \mbox{is even}
\end{array}\right.}
$$

Comment: That's a very neat and elegant reduction! $$\binom {1/2}{n/2}$$.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $n=1$, we have

$$k_3=0$$

It is clear that, for $n=3, 5, 7, ...$, 
$$k_{n+2}=0$$
Hence $k_n=0$ for all odd $n\geq3$. $\qquad \blacksquare$

Now consider the case for even $n$, i.e. where $n=2m$.

The recurrence relation becomes
$$\begin{align}
k_{2m+2}
&=\frac{1-2m}{2m+2}k_{2m}\\[10pt]
&=-\frac{2m-1}{2m+2}k_{2m}\\[10pt]
&=\left(\prod_{r=1}^{m}(-1)^r\frac{2r-1}{2r+2}\right)\color{red}{k_2}\\[10pt]
&=(-1)^m\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2m-1)}{4\cdot6\cdot 8\cdots (2m+2)}\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{2m+1}{2m+1}}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{k_0}2} \\[10pt]
&=(-1)^m\frac{1}{\color{blue}{2m+1}}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots \color{blue}{(2m+1)}}{\color{red}2\cdot 4\cdot6\cdots
(2m+2)}\color{red}{k_0}\\[10pt]
&=(-1)^m\frac{1}{2m+1}\cdot \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2m+1)}{2^{m+1}(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (m+1))}\cdot\color{green}{\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot6\cdots 
(2m+2)}{2^{m+1}(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (m+1))}}k_0\\[10pt]
&=(-1)^m\frac{1}{2m+1}\cdot \frac1{2^{2m+2}}\cdot\frac{(2m+2)!}{(m+1)!(m+1)!}k_0\\[10pt]
&=(-1)^m\frac{1}{(2m+1)2^{2m+2}}\binom{2m+2}{m+1}k_0\\[10pt]
k_{2m}&=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{1}{(2m-1)2^{2m}}\binom{2m}{m}k_0\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

---

EDITED: Alternatively, as inspired by the answer from Felix Marin below, the case for even $n$ can be derived as follows:

$$\begin{align}
k_{2m+2}
&=\frac{1-2m}{2m+2}k_{2m}\\[10pt]
&=-\frac{2m-1}{2m+2}k_{2m}\\[10pt]
&=\left(\prod_{r=1}^{m}(-1)^r\frac{2r-1}{2r+2}\right)\color{red}{k_2}\\[10pt]
&=(-1)^m\cdot \frac{\color{green}1
\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2m-1)}{\color{red}2\cdot 4\cdot6\cdot 8\cdots
(2m+2)}\color{red}{k_0}\\\\
&=\frac{\frac12\left(-\frac 12\right)\left(-\frac32\right)\left(-\frac52\right)\cdots \left(-\frac{2m-1}2\right)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots (m+1)}k_0\\\\
&=\binom{1/2}{m+1}k_0\\\\
k_{2m}&=\binom{1/2}{m}k_0\\\\
k_{n}&=\binom{1/2}{n/2}k_0\qquad\text{(for even $n$)}\qquad \blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: Elegant. Much better than my answer.

Comment: @user170039 - Thank you! Very nice of you to say :)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $k_3=0$, and by an easy induction $k_{2m+1}=0$ for $m\ge 1$. It’s not hard to work out and then prove by induction on $m$ that

$$\begin{align*}
k_{2m}&=(-1)^{m-1}\cdot\frac{(2m-3)(2m-5)\ldots(3)(1)(1)}{(2m)(2m-2)\ldots(4)(2)}k_0\\\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\cdot\frac{(2m-3)!!}{(2m)!!}k_0\\\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{(2m-3)!!}{2^mm!}k_0\\\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{(2m-2)!}{2^mm!\cdot2^{m-1}(m-1)!}k_0\\\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\frac{(2m-2)!}{2^{2m-1}m(m-1)!^2}k_0\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2^{2m-1}m}\binom{2m-2}{m-1}k_0\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{2^{2m-1}}C_{m-1}k_0\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $C_{m-1}$ is the $(m-1)$-st [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

Comment: Nice answer, with double factorials and Catalan numbers!

Comment: @hypergeometric: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**, $n=2h, h\in \mathbb{N}$

$k_{2(h+1)}=(-1)\left(1-\dfrac{3}{2(h+1)}\right)k_{2h}=(-1)^{h+2}\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^h\left(1-\dfrac{3}{2(i+1)}\right)k_0$

**Case 2**, $n=2h+1, h\in \mathbb{N}$

Similar analysis.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please ? I am stuck.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: At which part are you stuck?

Comment: Trying to express $k_n$ as function of $k_0$ and $k_1$ as asked in the post. I don't see how your answer can help for arriving to a closed form. The pattern is hard to find.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Is it clear now?